# Stripe is allowing successful transactions when using their test cards that are designed to fail

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hello and thanks for your time,
I am using the legacy version of Stripe Checkout, the one with the modal dialog, in a PHP environment.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="<?php echo $stripe['pub_key']; ?>"
data-email="<?php echo $loggedInUser->email; ?>"
data-amount="1000" 
data-description="One Credit Purchase ($10.00)"
data-image="img/charge-logo.png"
data-name="Sheet"
data-panel-label="One Credit - "
data-label="One Credit - $10.00"
data-zip-code=TRUE
data-billing-address=TRUE>
</script>
```

And the charge page:

```
try {
                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                    'amount'   => 1000,
                    'currency' => 'usd',
                    'customer' => $_POST['customer_id'],
                    'description' => "Single Credit Purchase"
                ));
            } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
                // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_AuthenticationError $e) {
                // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
                // Network communication with Stripe failed
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Stripe_Error $e) {
                // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
                // yourself an email
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
                $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
                }
```

My Stripe account is in test mode, and I am attempting to test this workflow using their published test cards.  Specifically the ones that are designed to decline:

4000000000000002  card_declined

4000000000009995  insufficient_funds

4000000000009987  lost_card

and so on.  The problem is, no matter what input I provide, the charge always succeeds.  I can put in any of the above card numbers, a bogus expiration date (i.e. 03/1969), and any CVC number, and the charge just goes right through.

The charge.succeeded event shows the charge object (abridged) as successful:

```
{
  "object": {
    "object": "charge",
    "amount": 1000,
    "paid": true,
    "status": "succeeded"
  }
}
```

I would expect to see something different.  I have tried the new smart payment page hosted by Stripe that creates payments for you, and all of the cards work as expected, providing the appropriate decline reasons.  Perhaps it is because the old version is deprecated?  Or am I missing something?

Just wondering if anyone still uses the legacy version, or has had experience with the test cards not working as expected, or again, am I missing something?

Thanks for your time!

Cheers!

Comment: I think Test mode is created for testing the payment gateway by successful transactions. Please see the payment gateway documentation for usual error codes that generates by the payment gateway for more details.

Answer (score 0):

That code you posted doesn't seem to actually charge the token created by Checkout. You only pass the `'customer' => $_POST['customer_id'],` so what happens is the Charge API charges the default card already attached to the particular customer(which is probably something else like a successful test card).

Hard to say without seeing all your code, but probably you don't actually use the token from the card information entered in Checkout(which would be `$_POST[stripeToken]`) anywhere so you're not actually testing that.

Also you should not use this integration at all and should switch to the new hosted page, Stripe considers it fully deprecated and it doesn't work for 3D Secure which is really important.